# Is LLVM bitcast from vector of bool (i1) to i8, i16, etc. well defined?

Tags: llvm, simd, endianness, llvm-ir

In LLVM, can a value of type `<8 x i1>` be bitcasted to an `i8`? If so what is the expected bit order? The [LLVM documentation on bitcast](https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#bitcast-to-instruction) is not explicit on this. The claim it makes is

> The `bitcast` instruction converts `value` to type `ty2`. It is always a *no-op cast* because no bits change with this conversion. The conversion is done as if the value had been stored to memory and read back as type `ty2`.

Tangentially, on the mailing list, it has been clarified that *no-op cast* [does not mean what it sounds like](http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-dev/2013-August/064922.html). Back to the issue at hand, the problem I see with bitcasting `<8 x i1>` to any other type (not just `i8`) is that a value of type `<8 x i1>` cannot be stored to memory. I have confirmed this experimentally (code not included), and it is also [well-documented on the mailing list](http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-dev/2016-August/103678.html). Since storing values of type `<8 x i1>` leads to undefined behavior, the specification "as if the value had been stored to memory and read back as type `ty2`" implies that any bitcast to or from `<8 x i1>` results in undefined behavior. Note that a [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38345682/conversion-of-vector-of-bools-to-integer-in-llvm-ir) has been asked before, but the answers to this question do not provide a satisfactory answer to the general soundness issue presented here. The author of the aforementioned issue resolved the issue by bitcasting `<8 x i1>` to `<1 x i8>`, but this cast involves an argument of type `<8 x i1>`, so I am not convinced that it is sound.

For what it's worth, in some of my own small tests with LLVM, I have confirmed that bitcasting `<8 x i1>` to `i8` works. Below is a function that tests 8 `i16`s at a time for whether or not they are each equal to 42.

```
; Filename is equality-8x16.ll
define void @equals42(<8 x i16>* %src0,i8* %dst0,i64 %len0) { ; i32()*
entry:
    %len = udiv exact i64 %len0, 8
    br label %cond
cond:
    %i = phi i64 [ 0, %entry ], [ %isucc, %loop ]
    %src = phi <8 x i16>* [ %src0, %entry ], [ %srcsucc, %loop ]
    %dst = phi i8* [ %dst0, %entry ], [ %dstsucc, %loop ]
    %cmp = icmp slt i64 %i, %len
    br i1 %cmp, label %loop, label %end
loop:
    %isucc = add i64 %i, 1
    %srcsucc = getelementptr <8 x i16>, <8 x i16>* %src, i64 1
    %dstsucc = getelementptr i8, i8* %dst, i64 1
    %val = load <8 x i16>, <8 x i16>* %src
    %bits = icmp eq <8 x i16> %val, <i16 42,i16 42,i16 42,i16 42,i16 42,i16 42,i16 42,i16 42>
    %res = bitcast <8 x i1> %bits to i8
    store i8 %res, i8* %dst
    br label %cond
end:
    ret void;
}
```

And here's some C code (`call-equality.c`) that calls it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define SZ 8

void equals42(void*,void*,int64_t);

/* Prints the highest bit first and the lowest bit last */
void printbits(uint8_t x)
{
    for(int i=sizeof(x)<<3; i; i--)
        putchar('0'+((x>>(i-1))&1));
}

int main(){
  uint16_t a[SZ * 8] = {0};
  uint8_t b[8];
  a[1] = 42;
  a[15] = 42;
  equals42(a,b,SZ * 8);
  for(int i = 0; i < SZ; i++){
    printf("Index %d:",i);
    printbits(b[i]);
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

Build, link, and run with:

```
llc-9 -O3 -mcpu=skylake -filetype=obj equality-8x16.ll
gcc call-equality.c equality-8x16.o
./a.out
```

And here's the results:

```
Index 0:00000010
Index 1:10000000
Index 2:00000000
Index 3:00000000
Index 4:00000000
Index 5:00000000
Index 6:00000000
Index 7:00000000
```

This works, and it even happens to do what I expect. This bits at positions 1 and 15 are set (interpreting byte 1, bit position 7 as bit position 15). However, it's not clear whether or not I would get the same results on a big endian platform (I'm using a little-endian Skylake CPU). Again, I'd like to stress that LLVM's official documentation does not document the behavior of bitcasts involving `<8 x i1>`.

The question is not just "does this happen to work on your computer or mine". (Although if someone has a big-endian platform, I would be curious to see if the example program gives the same results). The real questions are:

- Is there some quasi-authoritative source, even if it's just mailing list threads and issue trackers, that specifies the semantics of these bitcasts?
- If these bitcasts are unsound, what is the idiomatic way to convert a `<8 x i1>` to an `i8`? It is possible to project out all eight bits individually (via `extractelement`) and then build an `i8` with some ORs and bitshifts, but that seems both tedious and relies heavily on an optimization pass to get the shuffle operation I would expect. Is there something better?

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing I've found so far is [a mailing list thread](https://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-dev/2018-December/128181.html) from 2018 where a user notices a problem where `bitcast <16 x i1> %a1 to i16` is poorly optimized. A maintainer responds, offering a fix in `r348104` (which I'm not able to find on GitHub or Phabricator). But this seems to imply that `bitcast <16 x i1> %a1 to i16` is understood to be well defined. But what is it actually supposed to mean? Is element 0 supposed to be bit position 0 in the resulting word? I think so, but it would be nice to see this spelled out somewhere.